# Using file metadata with AWS Elastic Transcoder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-transcoder

When uploading video files to my S3 bucket, I can include custom metadata:

```
x-amz-client-id
x-amz-timestamp
x-amz-pretty-name
```

What I'm wondering is, once these videos enter an Elastic Transcoder pipeline, is there any way to include this metadata, say, in the "complete" notification the Elastic Transcoder sends out? The intent is to, once a file is processed, use the returned data to update database records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do just that now using the UserMetadata filed introduced on Dec-10-2014. See [Amazon Elastic Transcoder Now Supports Pass-Through Metadata for Jobs](http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2014/12/10/amazon-elastic-transcoder-now-supports-metadata-pass-through-for-jobs/). Include these values on the job when it is created, and the SNS notification will include the provided metadata.